# Assert that my C# function throws the same exception as another function

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

So in the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` namespace there's an assert function `Assert.ThrowsException<T>(Action)` that tests if `Action` throws an exception of type `T`.

But `<T>` means I have to know beforehand what exception will be thrown.

Let's say that I'm creating a method that should throw an exception similar to another method whose code is still 'fluid' (spec still changing). Let's call my function `MyClass.Func` and the other function `UpstreamClass.Func`.

(Both `MyClass` and `UpstreamClass` inherits from `ICommonInterface`, which defines `public void Func(int)`)

Is there a way to assert that, when fed arguments that should throw exception in both functions, the thrown exceptions are the same type?

Or, in (made-up) code:

```cs
// Assume -1 should generate an exception
Assert.ThrowSameException(UpstreamClass.Func(-1), MyClass.Func(-1));
```

Comment: Could you catch the exception, and compare the `GetType()`?

Comment: @mjwills hmm... that's an interesting out-of-the-box thought... I can do some experiments along that line... though I'm certain I'll hate the boilerplate code :-P

Comment: So you want to test if both methods throw the same type of exception, right? If so, a simple solution would be to catch the exception of methodA store the type of it in a variable, catch the exception of methodB and compare the types.EDIT: uups way to late :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use such a method:

```
public static bool AllThrowSameException(params Action[] actions)
{
    Type lastExceptionType = null;
    foreach (Action action in actions)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (lastExceptionType?.Equals(ex.GetType()) == false)
                return false;
            lastExceptionType = ex.GetType();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The test would be:

```
Assert.IsTrue(AllThrowSameException(() => UpstreamClass.Func(-1), () => MyClass.Func(-1)));
```

Comment: Whoa, this is awesome! Thanks!